# Score on the test set is higher than on the training set, wrong approach?

Tags: python, machine-learning, grid-search, hyperparameters

I have a relatively small, imbalanced data set (~3k datapoints, 12 classes). I want to tune the parameters of a `RandomForestClassifier` and eventually test the model.

Currently I'm doing it like this, but strangely it yields higher scores on the test set than on the training set (I used cohen_kappa_score and accuracy)

```
#Split data in training and test set (70/30 stratified split)
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_Distances, Y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42, stratify=Y)

#Scorings used for parameter tuning evaluation
scoring = {'Accuracy' : make_scorer(accuracy_score), 'Recall' : 'recall_macro', 'Kappa' : make_scorer(cohen_kappa_score)}

#Initializing of parameter ranges
params_randomSearch = {"min_samples_leaf": np.arange(1,30,2),
              "min_samples_split": np.arange(2,20,2),
              "max_depth": np.arange(2, 20, 2),
              "min_weight_fraction_leaf": np.arange(0. ,0.4, 0.1),
              "n_estimators": np.arange(10, 1000, 100),
              "max_features" : ['auto', 'sqrt', 'log2', None],
              "criterion" : ['entropy', 'gini']}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rs = RandomizedSearchCV(RandomForestClassifier(random_state=42), param_distributions=params_randomSearch, scoring = scoring, cv = 3, refit = 'Kappa', n_iter=60, n_jobs=-1, random_state=42)
    rs.fit(x_train, y_train)
    print('Best Score: ', rs.best_score_, '\nBest parameters: ', rs.best_params_)
    y_predict = rs.best_estimator_.predict(x_test)
    acc = cohen_kappa_score(y_test, y_predict)
```

Results - Accuracy:

```
best_score_ = {float64} 0.5103216514642342
best_params_ = {dict} {'n_estimators': 310, 'min_weight_fraction_leaf': 0.0, 'min_samples_split': 12, 'min_samples_leaf': 5, 'max_features': 'auto', 'max_depth': 14, 'criterion': 'entropy'}

# 1. Eval
Accuracy of base (default) classifier on test set:  0.47928331466965285
Accuracy of classifier with best_params of RandomSearchCV on test set:  0.5666293393057111
```

Same results for the `cohen_kappa_score`, interestingley I get the exact same model using 'Kappa' as `refit` score

I don't know if this is an acceptable result or if something is wrong with my approach. Since the dataset is small, maybe the test set is just "easier"?

EDIT: `random_state = 1` on data split Results with `cohen_kappa`:

```
best_params_ = {dict} {'n_estimators': 310, 'min_weight_fraction_leaf': 0.0, 'min_samples_split': 12, 'min_samples_leaf': 5, 'max_features': 'auto', 'max_depth': 14, 'criterion': 'entropy'}
best_score_ = {float64} 0.4302884321273102
best_estimator on test set: 0.45628479220654583
```

Comment: Have you tried other random seeds?

Comment: how large are the training and test sets?

Comment: Train:2083, Test: 893, I will try another random seed right away - just wanted to verify if my whole approach is wrong.

Comment: I updated the initial post with the second run with another random_state